# How I can make Mandatory add at least one row in Interactive grid in apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

I have  two region one form and one interactive grid like a master detail(company and company contact person ) how i can make the interactive grid mandatory ,the user can't submit page ,he/she need  add at least one row in interactive grid ,
I can do that or I need to change the interactive grid to collection and count the row in validation

Comment: You said the user can't submit the page. Why not? Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to validate the value on submit? I'll provide an answer that takes this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is a little tricky because of the way processes and validations work with Interactive Grids (they are executed once per submitted row). To work around this, I'll use a page item and a validation that works with it.

The basic idea of this solution is based on the fact that a new row will not have a primary key value. Here are the steps to reproduce (my example was on page 14, update the following as needed).

1. Create an Interactive Grid (IG) region. The primary key column should be Query Only (which ensures it's null for new rows).
2. Create a Hidden page item named P14_NULL_FOUND. Set Type under Server-side Condition to Never so that it never renders on the page.
3. Create an After Submit (before Validations) process. This process will NOT be associated with the IG so it will only fire once. Set the PL/SQL Code attribute to:

   ```
   :P14_NULL_FOUND := 'NO';
   ```

   That will clear out the value of the page item prior to the next process.
4. Create another After Submit process that runs just after the previous one. Set Editable Region to the IG. Then set the PL/SQL Code to something like the following:

   ```
   if :PK_COLUMN_IN_IG is null
   then
     :P14_NULL_FOUND := 'YES';
   end if;
   ```

   You'll need to replace ":PK_COLUMN_IN_IG" with the name of the primary key column in the IG, such as ":EMPNO". This process will be run once for each submitted row in the IG. If a null value is found for the primary key column, then that would mean the user added a new row and the value of P14_NULL_FOUND would be set to 'YES'.
5. Create a new validation. This validation will NOT be associated with the IG so it will only fire once. Set Type to PL/SQL Expression. Set PL/SQL Expression to:

   ```
   :P14_NULL_FOUND != 'NO'
   ```

   Then set Error Message to something relevant.

At this point, you should be able to run the page and verify that the processes and validation are working correctly.

Comment: Thank dear for every support , I have onther question how I can change the name in above alert  message, 172.1.1.12 says  how I can change this to CRM says

Comment: I didn't use an `alert` above. The validation error message in #5 is displayed as an APEX alert which should not have the "host says" title. Maybe you added an `alert` somewhere else? At any rate, you can't change that. You could use `apex.message.alert` instead, which uses a jQuery dialog message without the title you don't want: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/apex.message.html#.alert

Comment: Oh sorry , this another question, I know you didn't use alter above

Comment: I see. Use the link above to learn about `apex.message.alert` and use that instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an another solution;

1. Create a page item like PX_ROWCOUNT which will hold the data of the row count of your IG.
2. Assign a static ID to your IG region.
3. Write a JS function to count the rows of the grid then set it to the page item. Sample function;

```
    function f_setRowCount(){
        var grid = apex.region("staticIDOfYourIG").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
        var model = grid.model;
        var rowCount = 0;
        model.forEach(function (record) {
            rowCount ++;
        });
        $s("PX_ROWCOUNT",rowCount);
    }
```

4. To submit your page and run this function, change your submit button's behavior to Defined by Dynamic Action. Execute your function when user clicks to that button then submit your page via DA.
5. Add validation to Processing section of the page and check your page item there; PLSQL Expression => :PX_ROWCOUNT > 0

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Hamit works nicely, **except of the case of deletion of a row.**
My suggestion is to amend the above code by adding inside the loop an if statement to check whether the row is editable or no.
So the code will be

```js
    var grid = apex.region("staticIDOfYourIG").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
var model = grid.model;
var rowCount = 0;

model.forEach(function (record) {
    if (model.allowEdit(record)) {
                rowCount ++;
    }
});
$s("PX_ROWCOUNT",rowCount);
```