# How to validate an Interactive Grid that is empty when the submit button is pressed

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5.1

Env: Oracle APEX v5.1 with Oracle 12c Release 2

I have an Interactive Grid that isn't based off an underlying table as I will process this manually using Target Type: PL/SQL.

I have been using the following as a guide:

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6361/index-en.html
```

My Interactive Grid query is as follows:

```
select  
  level as id,  
  level as grid_row,  
  null as product,  
  null as product_item  
from dual connect by level <= 1
```

In addition to this, I am using my own "Submit" button that calls my Target Type PL/SQL page process.

My question is, when the user presses the "Submit" button without actually entering any column data or adding any additional rows of information, how can I validate this, so that a notification message appears, indicating that no information has been provided at all?

At the moment, the whole page submits, which is what I want to prevent if nothing has been entered into the IG.

Comment: Hi Tony, could you please see my answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827242/how-i-can-make-mandatory-add-at-least-one-row-in-interactive-grid-in-apex-oracle/59864913

Comment: I don't know if this was the case with 5.1, but at some point the submit changed to Ajax-based processing. If you use validations to do the check, then the response should map any validation errors back to the page so it doesn't have to do a full page reload.

Comment: @DanMcGhan Appreciate the reply. I will take a look at your answer to that other question. Just with regards to your second point, can you please elaborate on "If you use validations to do the check..." - sorry, I don't understand what you mean here? It would be good if there was a flag that you could set to indicate the IG required atleast one entry to be entered.

Comment: I just mean if you validated the data using validations rather than inside the PL/SQL process that's going to work with the data. Let me know if the other post helps you implement a solution.