# Oracle Apex Print collection value in validation for debugging

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a validation process for my Interactive Grid and i am debugging an issue.

For that i want to print the value of collection but am unable to.

```
Declare
var1 varchar2(100);
var2 varchar2(100);
v_error varchar2(1000);

Begin
select c001,listagg(c002 ,'-') within group (order by c002) coo2_list into var1,var2 from apex_collections 
     where collection_name='MY_COLLECTION' 
     group by c001;

//Followed by For loop (can't write code due to restrictions)..

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
v_error := "Error due to "||var2";
END;
```

Var2 doesn't print anything

Comment: Use apex_debug api to print values in debug

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous question, I'm assuming this is a validation on an interactive grid on that collection. A validation runs before a page submit, so the values are not saved to the database yet. The code you posted checks the values that are in the database, it will not validate the user input.

It seems you want to validate that at least one rows exists in the interactive grid. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827242/how-i-can-make-mandatory-add-at-least-one-row-in-interactive-grid-in-apex-oracle) question - it is similar to that.